# Why do I get a "the location is not a folder" error when trying to open files using Dash or Synapse?

Tags: 11.04, unity, unity-dash, synapse

Within the last few days, I've encountered errors when trying to open files using Unity Dash, Synapse, or even the Gnome Search Tool.

These methods will let me launch applications and folders, but not files of any time, including mp3, doc, odt, and txt. With any method, the same error dialogue results: "the location is not a folder". Is there something I can do on my end to correct this, or is this a bug in Natty that is still being corrected?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`sudo apt-get remove exo-utils`

this is from xfce. You might need to remove thunar as well.
Fixed it for me anyway.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. I had exo-utils installed when I installed Thunar. Once I removed exo-utils (Thunar was removed, too), the problem was resolved.

Comment: for me, 39 packets, including xubuntu-desktop, should be removed. is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Had the same problem when using Calibre -- fixed using this method. Question is, is this a bug or a feature? :)

Comment: Removing exo-utils removes thunar and lot's of essential stuff from xfce4 desktop. It is not very good solution

Answer (score 4):

[Here is the solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/exo/+bug/775640/comments/10) without removing exo-utils:

> If you want to simply fix the opening
>   of files but retain XFCE/exo you can
>   simply open
>   "exo-preferred-applications" and
>   change the preferred "file manager"
>   under "utilities" back to "Thunar"
>
> I'm guessing the install of XFCE
>   changes this default, anyway flipping
>   it back to thunar certainly fixes the
>   behaviour in Unity for me.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a bug in exo-utils package. ([Reported Launchpad Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-place-files/+bug/751374))

It is an upstream problem with the desktop files which install wrong handlers for the things (that is if you do not use XFCE)...

The "MimeType=" entry in the:

```
/usr/share/applications/exo-file-manager.desktop
/usr/share/applications/exo-mail-reader.desktop
/usr/share/applications/exo-web-browser.desktop
```

files should become: "X-XFCE-MimeType="

A quick fix for your problem is to change the entry as needed and update your desktop file database.

Changing the entry can be done as root in a terminal this way:

```
sed -i -e 's/^MimeType=/X-XFCE-MimeType=/' \
     /usr/share/applications/exo-file-manager.desktop \
     /usr/share/applications/exo-mail-reader.desktop \
     /usr/share/applications/exo-web-browser.desktop
```

I have prepared a package with the fixed bug in my PPA, so you can install it (you may need to wait till it builds btw) ([PhobosK's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~phobosk/+archive/phobosk-ppa))

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a problem in xdg-open and gnome-open. There is a bug page for that problem here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-place-files/+bug/751374. You should try typing 'xdg-open '. If the file opens correctly then you're experiencing a different problem. If it gives the 'location is not a folder' error then keep and eye out for fixes to this but.

For the record xdg-open does not work for me, and uninstalling/reconfiguring some packages hasn't fixed it. Knowing which package needs removing/updating would be useful, molnarandris.

Comment: I have fixed this on my computer. After updating to natty beta xdg-open stopped working. I found this https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=112069 and it suggested that exo-open was the problem. After removing edo-utils and a few xfce related programs that depended on it, I can now open files from the dash without this error.

Answer (score 1):

Removing exo-utils also removes thunar. Some of us need to have both thunar and nautilus installed in gnome

Since the problem is exo-utils, I build a thunar .deb without the exo-utils dependency.
Here is how for **64bit**:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/69753654/thunar_1.2.1-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb
dpkg-deb -x thunar_1.2.1-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb tmpdir
dpkg-deb --control thunar_1.2.1-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb tmpdir/DEBIAN
gedit tmpdir/DEBIAN/control
```

Remove 'exo-utils' from the 'Depends' line and save

```
dpkg -b tmpdir thunar_1.2.1-3ubuntu2_amd64-no_exo-utils_dependency.deb
sudo apt-get remove exo-utils
sudo dpkg -i thunar_1.2.1-3ubuntu2_amd64-no_exo-utils_dependency.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

via: http://queleimporta.com/thunar-nautilus-exo-utils-and-the-location-is-not-a-folder-error-solution-under-gnome/

Answer (score 1):

Removing exo-utils also removes thunar. Some of us need to have both thunar and nautilus installed in gnome - this worked for me see the link http://queleimporta.com/thunar-nautilus-exo-utils-and-the-location-is-not-a-folder-error-solution-under-gnome/.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

Try to run computer janitor. For me, it solved the problem. I think it must be related to an old version of a panel or menu, or unneeded libraries.

Comment: Running the Computer Janitor did not work for me.

Comment: running computer janitor hs nothing to do with the problem