# "The location is not a folder" error when opening files

Tags: gnome, thunar, file-association

I'm aware of [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34260/why-do-i-get-a-the-location-is-not-a-folder-error-when-trying-to-open-files-usi) and i'm making a new one because that solutions there were not enough for my problem.

I installed xfce and pcmanfm on top of my vanilla ubuntu 10.10 installation.
After i got tired of them i uninstalled them.
And then in some programs (gnome-do, firefox, file-browser-applet, chrome) i get the error

> could not display the file'filename.txt' "the location is not a
>   folder"

when trying to open files that those programs manage.

As suggested by the previously mentioned question i tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove exo-utils
```

Not no avail, i got ubuntu Tweak and went to the file associations tab, and the folder filetype is set to open-folder is that ok?

Also i checked these files

```
/usr/share/applications/nautilus-computer.desktop
/usr/share/applications/nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
```

And they are the same as a clean 10.10 installation(i checked it with a virtual machine)
I tracked it to

`gnome-open 'the name of some file.pdf'`

And i get the same error, and i'm guessing that the programs sending that error are using some function() that calls gnome-open or something like that.
I also tried using the "exo-preferred-applications" to switch to nautilus, but it doesnt show the file-manager option as some suggested it would.

Right now i don't have the exo utils or anything exo installed, nothing Xfce specific.
I ran out of things to try, so any help is appreciated.

UPDATE

I tried installing the package XFCE and then login to that desktop and gnome-open works on xfce... strange
Also i got all the files on /usr/share/desktop from a clean 10.10 installation and copied over the files on my damaged installation and it didn't helped, is not an issue with them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it! I deleted my `~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/url-handlers` folder and now the problem is completely gone.

If you are interested, [this was the source](http://bugs.sabayon.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1448) of the idea.