# ubuntu 12.10 The location is not a folder

Tags: unity, upgrade, nautilus, permissions

i just upgraded my Ubuntu to 12.10 and i noticed that i get this message `The location is not a folder` whenever i try to access a mounted media (USB or even my other partitions). I am now unable to view content on my usb pendrive or other partitions.

already tried `sudo apt-get remove exo-utils` with no luck because it says it is not installed.

Can anyone help me?

UPDATE: this workaround seems to work for me https://askubuntu.com/a/204226/59618

Comment: ***What is the file-type?*** ***Did you upgrade or clean-install 11.10?***  This can happen when behavior for opening/copying a file or media is outdated / incorrect. **Somewhere there is a path that is no longer correct. Possibly in Nautilus configuration.**

Comment: I had a clean install on ubuntu 12.04. I now upgraded from it to 12.10

Comment: Whoops, I meant **12.10**.

Comment: Have you looked at this question? ["The location is not a folder" error when opening files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59761/the-location-is-not-a-folder-error-when-opening-files)

Comment: Me too having the same issue. http://askubuntu.com/questions/204119/mount-issue-muti-user-ubuntu-12-10#comment253756_204119

Comment: A.S that solution did not work for me either

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to access the device through command line or script that worked with 12.04 and previous versions?  They've changed the default mount point for USB devices so you might have to change the way you are doing things slightly to take it into account.

Previously USB devices were accessed at

> /media/volume

or

> /media/UUID

From now on it looks like these devices will need to be accessed at

> /media/username/volume

or

> /media/username/UUID

Yep, it's a pain, but I found that inserting $LOGNAME in my scripts seems to be taking care of it quickly and neatly.  For example instead of:

```
cp -nv /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /media/${args[0]}/archives/$release/
```

change to:

```
cp -nv /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /media/$LOGNAME/${args[0]}/archives/$release/
```

To repair any permissions problems make sure you own the drive and all subdirectories open a terminal window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> and :

```
sudo chown -R username:username /media/username/volume
```

such as:

```
sudo chown -R psychock7:psychock7 /media/psychoc7/BACKUP\ HDD
```

see if you can cd into the directories or if you get any errors.

```
cd /media
cd psychock7
cd backup\ hdd
cd dirname
```

etc.

You can use

```
ls
```

to get a directory listing, and use

```
ls -l
```

To get a long dirctory listing with extra information such as owner and access rights.

Comment: I am trying to acess it through nautilus/unity, not the terminal.. should i still do this?

Comment: No, it should already know where the mount point is.  It seems like something is broken.  You could plug your USB device in and have a look at the directory /media/username (your username) and see if it is mounting correctly though.  If it's there, I don't see why nautilus should be having a problem.

Comment: i got it working with SUDO... how can i change to make this the default behaviour?

Comment: It seems like a permissions problem.  Do you only have one user?

Comment: Yes only one user

Comment: Possibly, an ownership problem open a terminal windows and type :  'chown -R username:username /media/volume' where username is your username, and volume is the mount point - either the volume label or the UUID.

Comment: i tried 'sudo chown -R psychok7:/psychok7/media/BACKUP\ HDD' and also tried 'sudo chown -R psychok7:/media/psychok7/BACKUP\ HDD' and for both i got  'chown: missing operand after `psychok7:/media/psychok7/BACKUP HDD''

Comment: Spaces are in the wrong places.  Should be sudo chown -R psychock7:psychok7   /media/psychok7/BACKUP\ HDD

Comment: tried and still getting "the location is not a folder"

Comment: I've added information for looking at the directories with command line.  Try it out and let us know if/when you get any error messages.

Comment: when i "cd BACKUP\ HDD/"
i get a "bash: cd: BACKUP HDD/: Permission denied" with ls -l i get a  "drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Oct 19 20:27 BACKUP HDD
drwx------ 5 root root 4096 Oct 21 16:14 psychok7" . i should add that this psychok7 is my usb3 pen drive

Comment: You still have an ownership problem, you need to use the chown command to change ownership and permissions.  I've edited the instructions above to be be clearer, please read them carefully and try again.

Comment: yes i did the chown command before posting this results just forgot  to mention it

Comment: i found this workaround to be usefull http://askubuntu.com/a/204226/59618