# mount issue in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: mount, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“The location is not a folder” error when opening files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59761/the-location-is-not-a-folder-error-when-opening-files)

I'm having issue with latest Ubuntu 12.10. Let me make it more clear.

I'm having the following partitions in my Laptop.

```
  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    39997439    19997696   83  Linux 
/dev/sda2   *    40001850    81947564    20972857+  83  Linux
/dev/sda3        81947565   123877214    20964825   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       123887614   976773119   426442753    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       123887616   333602815   104857600   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       333604864   543320063   104857600   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       543322112   753037311   104857600   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       753039360   976773119   111866880   83  Linux
```

I have also two users named "ms" and abc. Here ms is for administrative tasks and abc for my friends. When I mount any drive under "abc" user, I cannot access it under my other user "ms".  Same as in the case with "ms" user. I found possible reason behind the issue. When I mount any drive under "abc" user, Ubuntu will try to mount it under "/media/abc/volume_name" instead of "/media/volume_name" . Same as in the case with "ms" user.

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        19G   11G  7.5G  59% /
udev            1.5G  4.0K  1.5G   1% /dev
tmpfs           599M  896K  598M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.5G  620K  1.5G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   92K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2        20G  172M   19G   1% /media/abc/TEST
/dev/sdb1       466G  353G  114G  76% /media/abc/F088F74288F7063E
/dev/sdb2       466G  318G  148G  69% /media/abc/New Volume
/dev/sda5        99G   94G  323M 100% /media/abc/Songs
/dev/sda6        99G   31G   63G  34% /media/ms/Films
```

Here, you can see that "TEST" was mounted under "/media/abc/TEST". When I try to access the already mounted partition named  '/media/abc/TEST" in my "ms" session I'm getting the following error.

---

[image: Please check the image for error message]

---

How to fix this error? Is it a bug? Is there any way to fix this without modifying the underlying file-system structure?

Comment: Seems like it is the intended behavior, not a bug http://askubuntu.com/questions/203841/ubuntu-12-10-the-location-is-not-a-folder

Comment: I had to edit your question. It was poorly formatted. For the next time please read http://askubuntu.com/editing-help . Thanks!

Comment: i found a possible workaround. Try to chmod 777 /media/user/  will  fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I found a possible workaround. Try to chmod 775 /media/user/ will fix the issue. Ie:

Normally, in  Ubuntu 12.10 it will try to mount volumes in the following format.

drwx------ root root /media/user

This is the reason why you are not able to browse the volumes under different user. So, please try to change the permission to "chmod 775 /media/user".

Answer (score 0):

the only workaround i found for now is using `gksudo nautilus`, this way i can access my partitions

Comment: Please note that if you're going to run Nautilus as `root`, it is preferable to use `gksu nautilus` or `gksudo nautilus` and **not** `sudo nautilus`, for the reasons [explained here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo).