# file:// protocol connected with wrong program

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, files, gnome2, protocol

I have the problem that when I open some programs/documents in Gnome, the wrong application is launched to open these.

I think I already narrowed the problem, that everything that is called with `file://` will be launched with the wrong program (in my case keepassx). I remember that when everything starts, I wanted to start keepassx from my gnome-panel. Ubuntu asked me with what program it should be started. I wondered a little, since I used it already a lot, so I choosed keepassx from the list. But it seems that this has overriden the file-protocol handler.

Some situations where the wrong program is called: shortcuts in my gnome panel (personal folder - which should open nautilus, keepassx, some txt files), synapse (launcher like gnome-do) and firefox finished downloads.

How can I reset this setting to get everything back to normal?

**Edit:**

The only reliable way to open files currently is via nautilus.

To give an example, a shortcut in the gnome-panel has the following properties:
Name: `myfile.txt`, Location: `file:///home/dag/myfile.txt`, Comment: `»/home/dag/myfile.txt« öffnen`

I use Ubuntu 11.04 with "Gnome-classic" aka Gnome2 2.32.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few places I can think of looking.  I'm not entirely sure how you got in this situation, so I'm not sure which is likeliest:

1. ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list (see if you have anything suspicious in there)
2. ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list (likewise)
3. Run gconf-editor, navigate to /desktop/gnome/url-handlers, and see if you have a file subdirectory in there.

Do any of those help?

Comment: Hi, thanks. The `mimeapps.list` shows an suspicious entry for exo-file-manager from xfce4 (which is installed for another user!):

    x-scheme-handler/file=exo-file-manager.desktop
    x-scheme-handler/trash=exo-file-manager.desktop

I found out that my question is also a duplicate to this issue: (http://askubuntu.com/questions/34260/why-do-i-get-a-the-location-is-not-a-folder-error-when-trying-to-open-files-us)

Somehow this helped me (didn't tried xfce since then): (http://queleimporta.com/thunar-nautilus-exo-utils-and-the-location-is-not-a-folder-error-solution-under-gnome/)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is right click to the file/properties/open with (tab) and select the program you want to use.
Maybe you can try too with Ubuntu Tweak to manage the file associations.

Comment: I can't choose the program when having the shortcut in the gnome-panel, synapse or the firefox downloads. I tried Ubuntu tweak, but the file associations are all correct. In fact the only way currently working to open something is via nautilus.