# How do I Prevent the file manager from opening when I click to open a file from outside the file manager

Tags: unity, nautilus, dolphin, synapse

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with awn and synapse installed and unity disabled. Whenever I search for a file on synapse and try to open it from there or from any other location, like a quick launcher from Awn, the system opens up the default file manager and navigates to the actual location, before it opens the file.

If the default file manager is set to nautilus, the file will actually not open. However I use dolphin as my default and while it does open the file and it does not hamper functionality, it is a very annoying action as it leaves unwanted file manager windows open.

How can I stop the system doing this without using Unity or opening the file directory from the file manager as some files are several directories deep?

Comment: Synapse uses `xdg-open` to find the right file type handler, afaik. Can you tell me what happens when you open a file of your choice with either `xdg-open`, `gnome-open` or `exo-open`? Try executing each of these with a file ( e.g. `xdg-open ~/.bashrc`). See here for related questions and bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-place-files/+bug/751374 https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=112069 http://askubuntu.com/questions/34260/why-do-i-get-a-the-location-is-not-a-folder-error-when-trying-to-open-files-us/36137#36137

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MHC Thanks for the links and suggestions. The problem was indeed with exo-utils. I installed it as an easier route to make dolphin the default file manager rather than editing a script. With exo-utils installed. xdg-open and gnome-open they opened the file as a folder and so called up the file manager. However exo-open will open the file straight. When I uninstalled exo-utils then gnome-open and xdg-open worked normally. I also realized that I had to set the files defaults from inside nautlius and not just dolphin if I want synapse to open files by default in my preferred application.