# Why does Synapse use Nautilus for all file types instead of the default application?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, xdg-open, synapse

No matter which file I find via [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project), it just gets opened in Nautilus. May that be because I recently put Nautilus as my default file manager?

Can I change that behavior to the normal action, i.e. an `.ods` file gets opened with LibreOffice Calc, `.txt` with Mousepad... and so on?

**Additional information:**

I am running Xubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Have you tried messsing around with `xdg-open` and similar tools as proposed in [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/268654/how-do-i-prevent-the-file-manager-from-opening-when-i-click-to-open-a-file-from)?

Comment: From what I gathered, there seems to be a conflict or so with `exo-utils`, right? I tried to uninstall `exo-utils`, but it is a dependency of many xfce4-plugins so it doesn not work out. Hm, I think I could do [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/58431/125988) although it is for 11.04 which was 2,5 years ago.

Comment: The workaround in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1753442 worked for me! > "If you want to simply fix the opening of files but retain XFCE/exo you can simply open "exo-preferred-applications" and change the preferred "file manager" under "utilities" back to "Thunar"

I'm guessing the install of XFCE changes this default, anyway flipping it back to thunar certainly fixes the behaviour in Unity for me. "